# Real-time thread updates issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working with many threads in a system where I know beforehand the total size of all files.  When an observer is notified of a change by the subject it implicitly knows a file segment has been downloaded.  I'll change this in the future as it's not explicit.

The problem I'm having is that my percentage indicator doesn't get updated if I deal with any other variables.  Here's a snippet:

```
    public delegate void ChangeUI(object subject); 

    public void Update(object subject)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new ChangeUI(Update), new object[] { subject });
            return;
        }

        lock (otherlock)
        {
            toolstripStatus.Text = ((++totalDownloadedSegments / totalLengthAllFiles) * 100).ToString() + "% completed.";
        }

        // update the percentage indicator etc. (works fine)
        //toolstripStatus.Text = ((FileDownloader)subject).PercentageCompleted().ToString() + "% completed.";
    }
```

I'm using the `this.InvokeRequired` for thread-safety issues so ignore that.  The line which is commented out works fine, but the one within the lock just doesn't work at all, with or without the lock.  `totalDownloadedSegments` is a local variable, as is `totalLengthAllFiles` (which stays the same throughout and isn't modified).

As you can see, I'm not very good on the threading front.  I basically want a percentage indicator to find out how much of all files I have downloaded in a percentage in the end.

Comment: As a diagnostic, does the UI seem to be "frozen"?

Comment: Are you sure `totalDownloadedSegments` and `totalLengthAllFiles` are actually getting updated?  Do you have the same lock around the code that updates those fields?

Comment: Yup, just checked, they are definitely being updated.

Comment: wait a moment, did you just say totalDownloadedSegments is a LOCAL variable? surely that can't be right?

Comment: local to the overall class, yes.  I don't think that's the problem though after doing some debugging.  `totalLengthAllFiles == 45646663`.  If I do `500 / 45646663` then I'll get `0` as the answer, I'm assuming this is because the number is too big (well, after the decimal place) as the answer in my calculator is `1.095370323127454e-5`.  You can see the predicament here!

Comment: ahhh, i just wrote that answer below Kezzer :-)
Well debugged
That has caught me out on several occasions

Answer (score 3):

You've done a good job at discovering the InvokeRequired.

Be careful that totalDownloadedSegments and totalLengthAllFiles arent integers though

Because if you have 99/100 as an integer, it will become 0 !!! be very very careful

So instead of

```
((++totalDownloadedSegments / totalLengthAllFiles) * 100)
```

Try

```
(100 * ++totalDownloadedSegments) / totalLengthAllFiles
```

or cast them them to floats first!

Comment: This is definitely on the right track.  They're currently of type `long` because I'm getting the information from type `FileInfo` anyway.  Casting them to `float` and doing it your way gives me something better, although not right.

Answer (score 0):

From apps that I've done multi threading I think you need to do this:

```
 if (toolstripStatus.InvokeRequired)
  {
      toolstripStatus.BeginInvoke(new ChangeUI(Update), new object[] { subject });
      return;
  }
   //Update here, Lock Variables that are global and could be used by other threads.
```

Comment: `toolStripStatus` is a UI object, it doesn't have `InvokeRequired` available on it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I used other controls e.g. list boxes etc., I have used this approach works fine for hundreds of concurrent threads updating it...